# Tick labels overlap axes with custom spines; making a "mathy" figure

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create a `mathy figure` where you literally draw the x- and y-axis.

```
function mathy_figure() # sorry this is PyPlot in Julia but works the same
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    ax = fig[:add_subplot](1, 1, 1)

    # Move left y-axis and bottom x-axis to center, passing through (0,0)
    ax[:spines]["left"][:set_position]("zero")
    ax[:spines]["bottom"][:set_position]("zero")

    # Eliminate upper and right axes
    ax[:spines]["right"][:set_color]("none")
    ax[:spines]["top"][:set_color]("none")
    return fig, ax
end
```

works as I intend when I don't plot anything i.e. `mathy_figure()`:

[image]

but then for an actual plot the x- and y-ticks overlap the spines! What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

```
fig, ax = mathy_figure()
plt.plot(x, y, color="C3")
plt.plot(u, v, color="C1")
plt.axhline(y=N, color="k", linestyle="--")
plt.yticks([0, system.N], ["\$0\$", "\$N\$"])
plt.axvline(x=system.P₀, linestyle=":", color="k")
plt.xticks([0, system.P₀], ["\$0\$", "\$P_0\$"])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Putting the spines at "zero" means that the content may appear at positions where there are also labels. How would you like your plot to look like instead?

Comment: I want the plot to look exactly as it does but without the splines overlapping "0", "P_0", and "N". How can I move the tick labels and increase padding?

Answer (score 0):

the following snippet of code worked! Now the 0 tick does not intersect the axis!

```
# magic to prevent overlapping content
# see https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html
ax[:spines]["left"][:set_smart_bounds](true)
ax[:spines]["bottom"][:set_smart_bounds](true)

ax[:xaxis][:set_ticks_position]("bottom")
ax[:yaxis][:set_ticks_position]("left")
```

as for the `axhline()`, I had to pass `xmin=0.05` to prevent the overlap with the ytick label "N"